# How to combine two similar RxJS observable object arrays into one array of objects?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need assistance trying to get two HTTP GET responses that come object arrays and combine them into one object array for example

If possible I would like the array from http using rxjs more than likely to have a response that has all 3 objects in one array

like below

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

**.ts**

```
incidents$ = this.incidentService.getAll();
otherIncidents$ = this.otherIncidentsService.getAll();


ngOnInit() {


this.incidents$.subscribe(res => {
 console.log('first http GET request', res)
})

this.otherIncidents$.subscribe(res => {
 console.log('second http GET request', res)
 })
```

**Console**

```
second http GET request [{…}]
0: {incidentNumber: 19418, createdByName: "User", execSummaryFlag: 
false, followupEmail: null, …}
length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
exec-summary.component.ts:140 

first http GET request (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {incidentNumber: 19380, createdByName: "User", execSummaryFlag: false, 
followupEmail:null, …}
1: {incidentNumber: 19399, createdByName: "User", execSummaryFlag: false, 
followupEmail: null, …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use Rxjs [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to combine multiple observables and map the response to your requirement (using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator). Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

forkJoin({
  incident: incidents$,
  otherIncident: otherIncidents$,
})
.pipe(
  map(response => ([...response.incident, ...response.otherIncident]))
)
.subscribe(
  response => { // handle reponse },
  error => { // handle error }
);
```

RxJS `forkJoin` emits the last emitted value when all the observables complete.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat)

```
// RxJS v6+
import { of, concat } from 'rxjs';

concat(
  of(1, 2, 3),
  // subscribed after first completes
  of(4, 5, 6),
  // subscribed after second completes
  of(7, 8, 9)
)
  // log: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options:

1. [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) function: 
   "After all observables emit, emit values as an array"

```js
zip(this.incidents$, this.otherIncidents$).subscribe(...);
```

2. [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) operator:
   "Also provide the last value from another observable"

```js
this.incidents$
   .pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.otherIncident$),
   )
   .subscribe(...);
```

3. [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) function (very similar to `zip`)
   "When any observable emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each"

```js
combineLatest(this.incidents$, this.otherIncidents$).subscribe(...);
```

The three of them emits an array of both of the observable.

Answer (score 1):

you can

- use `forkjoin` to wait for both observables to return
- then use `switchMap` to change the result
- in the switchMap you can manipulate the arrays. in this case we use `Array.concat()` to generate a new array that combines the output of the two observables

  `forJoin({
    incident: this.incidents$,
    otherIncident: this.otherIncidents$
  })
  .pipe(
  switchMap ( response => response.incident.concat(response.otherIncident))
  ).subscribe(
      response => {//do something},
      error => {//handle error}
  );`

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to my Question**

```
ngOnInit(){

const incidents = this.incident.getAll();
const otherIncidents = this.otherService.getAll();
forkJoin([incidents, otherIncidents])
.subscribe(res => {
 this.execEntry=[...res[0], ...res[1]];
 console.log(this.execEntry);
})
}
```